# overflow : hidden hides content in placeholder object

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have an asp placeholder object, within a div.

```
<div id="contentMenu" class="contentMenu">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhMenu" runat="server">
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <div id="divMenuImage" class="menuImage">
        <asp:Image ID="imgMenu" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/menu.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

the div uses the following css:

```
.contentMenu
{
    color: #ffffff;
    left: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    width: 500px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Items in the menu are added to the placeholder using calls such as:

```
plhMenu.Controls.Add(btnArrow);
plhMenu.Controls.Add(btnCategory);
```

Using the text-overflow property in the css is supposed to crop the text and show ellipses.

However, when the property "overflow : hidden" is in the css, all the menu disappears. Remove that propery and the menu appears, but the text-overflow doesn't work (it seems that overflow : hidden is required).

Any help in sorting this out would be very much appreciated as I have spent hours trying to figure out what is going on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a height on your container div, if you are adding items to the placeholder dynamically after the page is first drawn, then they might not cause the div to grow vertically.

You could try using `overflow-x: hidden;`?

Comment: Well, I've tried overflow-x and setting both a fixed height and "auto" height. Neither work. As the div grows normally (ie without the overflow : hidden property), I suspect it is something else...

Comment: Is your background colour white by any chance? Your text is white, is it just hidden by being white on white?